# How to remove axis in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

`axis off` Not working.

```
function displayResults(filename,hObject, eventdata, handles)
% Open 'filename' file... for reading...
fid = fopen(filename);
for N=6:1:10
    imagename = fgetl(fid);
    if ~ischar(imagename), break, end       % Meaning: End of File...
    [x,map]=imread(imagename);
    rgb=ind2rgb(x,map);
    ax = handles.(sprintf('axes%d', N));
    axis off;
    image(rgb, 'Parent', ax);  
end
guidata(hObject,handles)
```

Above code results in following output:

[image]

I've highlighted axis in above figure.
All images I've used is bitmap with bit depth of 8. I don't want those axis, how can I remove that?

Answer (score 18):

insert the following at the end of each loop:

```
set(ax, 'Visible','off')
```

or you can do this once for all axes in the figure:

```
set(findobj(gcf, 'type','axes'), 'Visible','off')
```

Comment: thanks. To be fair, you could have also written: `axis(ax, 'off')` (explicitly specify target axes). Setting visible=off will also hide the `title` if present

Comment: Nice. I wasn't aware of this syntax, but now I look at `type axis` and recall a lot of interesting stuff :)